# Counting rows that fit into more than one category

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble displaying the results of a MySQL query correctly.

I have a table, trips, that lists the start and end time of car trips (the start and end is meassured in number of minutes after midnight).

```
id   start    end
1    0        120    // 00:00    02:00
2    60       90     // 01:00    01:30
3    0        150    // 00:00    02:30
etc...
```

I would like to count the number of 'active' car trips for every half hour, so that my result looks something like this:

```
period          count
00:00 - 00:30   2
00:30 - 01:00   2
01:00 - 01:30   3
01:30 - 02:00   2
02:00 - 02:30   1
02:30 - 03:00   0
```

*Note 1: Each row in the trips table may be counted towards more than one period.*

*Note 2: I think of start times as inclusive, and end times as non-inclusive, so that e.g. trip 2 is only counted as active in the period '13:00 - 13:30'.*

I have not been able to present the result in this way. My current query is:

```
SELECT
    sum(start < 30 AND end > 0) as '00:00 - 00:30',
    sum(start < 60 AND end > 30) as '00:30 - 01:00',
    sum(start < 90 AND end > 60) as '01:00 - 01:30',
    etc...
FROM
    trips;
```

which produces the following result:

```
00:00 - 00:30    00:30 - 01:00    01:00 - 01:30   etc...
2                2                3
```

To clarify, my solution produces the correct answer, but I want to display the result with one period per row, not one period per column.
I guess the solution is to use CASE together with GROUP BY, but I have so far been unsuccessful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create a table for the periods with `CREATE TABLE` or create one on the fly.

```
select period.text, count(*)
from
(
  select   0 as min_start,  30 as min_end, '00:00 - 00:30' as text
  union all
  select  30 as min_start,  60 as min_end, '00:30 - 01:00' as text
  union all
  select  60 as min_start,  90 as min_end, '01:00 - 01:30' as text
  union all
  select  90 as min_start, 120 as min_end, '01:30 - 02:00' as text
  union all
  select 120 as min_start, 150 as min_end, '02:00 - 02:30' as text
  union all
  select 150 as min_start, 180 as min_end, '02:30 - 03:00' as text
) period
left join mytable on mytable.min_start < period.min_end
                  and mytable.min_end > period.min_start
group by period.text;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8df7d/5